# How to get rid of an arrow in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I want to put a crossing on an edge. I do it in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[-latex,auto,
bkeg/.style={draw=red!30}]
\draw[bkeg] (0,0) to [bend left] node [black, pos=0.3, auto=false, cross out, draw]{} (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here I get the crossing :

[image]

How to get rid of the arrow and in the second line of the crossing? Is it posible to reset this "-latex" option in the slave node?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can just set `-` (like a line without an arrow) as a `node` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[-latex,auto,
bkeg/.style={draw=red!30}]
\draw[bkeg] (0,0) to [bend left] node [black, pos=0.3, auto=false, cross out, -, draw]{} (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```